# JAVA: Hacer un casteo de String a Int dentro de un try catch con variables con nombres incrementales

Tags: java, try-catch, cast

como dice en el título estoy intentando una forma en la que en un sólo bucle poder hacer con un try catch el casteo de muchas variables a la vez aprovechando que esas variables tienen nombres incrementales tipo: s1,s2,s3,s4...
concatenando para apuntar a dichas variables. Un ejemplo de código que querría hacer es esto:

```
public class JavaStringToIntExample
{
 public static void main (String[] args)
 {
   // String s = "fred";  // use this if you want to test the exception below
   String s1 = "100";
   String s2 = "101";
   String s = "s";
   try
   {
     // the String to int conversion happens here
     for(int i=0;i<2;i++){
        int j = Integer.parseInt(s+"+"+i).trim();
        System.out.println(j);
}
     // print out the value after the conversion
   }
   catch (NumberFormatException nfe)
   {
     System.out.println("NumberFormatException: " + nfe.getMessage());
   }
 }
}
```

Comment: ¿Cual es tu pregunta?

Comment: No se entiende nada lo que quieres hacer, edita la pregunta.

Answer (score 0):

Si entendi a donde quieres llegar, te comento que deberias modificar las lineas que se encuentran dentro del ciclo for.

```
// the String to int conversion happens here
for(int i=0;i<2;i++){
    int j = Integer.parseInt(s+"+"+i).trim();
    System.out.println(j);
 }
```

Por lo siguiente:

```
// the String to int conversion happens here
 for(int i=0;i<2;i++){
    System.out.println(s + i);
}
```

Ya que no es necesario hacer un parseInt ya que I es de tipo entero y es imposible hacer un cast a una letra.

Espero te ayude.
Saludos.